# Is there anyway round robin through servers in RetroFit?

Tags: java, retrofit

Specifically, if I have a set of servers that all expose the same REST api, in RetroFit is there a way to specify that set of servers, or is the only option to instantiate multiple retrofit clients and circle through them?

Answer (score 0):

The `Server` class can already support this by subclassing and changing what you return from `getUrl()`. We designed it this way for this explicit purpose.

See more discussion here: https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/385